# Java: How to use Keyboard in program

Tags: java, keyboard, key

I know that there is lots of sources of that but i can't find anything useful for me. so, - im creating little program/game. There is Dialogues Which asking stuff about character for example name, etc (i used Scanner for that) but now i need to make so that There will be chooseable options for example where you born: A. Something1 B. Something2 C. Something3. So when you press For example B on keyboard, you will choose "Something2". its little bit messed up question but please answer me, thanks.

Comment: You need a keytyped Event .

Comment: I think what you need is _java.awt.event.KeyEvent_ and _java.awt.event.KeyListener_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the key listener .

get the keycode from Keyboard and do the actions accordingly :

Here is the Tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Hint :

```
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char keyPress=e.getKeyChar();
        if keyPress=='a' or 'A' 
            select option 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a game, I am guessing you are going to use Swing or AWT to display your stuff.

If it is the case, then you have to listen for key events. There are two ways:

#### Using KeyListener

You register listeners to your components. See [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

The problem here is that you may have several components and it's impractical to attach listener to all of them. On the other hand, if you just have a big Canvas, then there is no hassle to do it.

#### Using KeyboardFocusManager

You can listen to all key events in your application by adding a custom KeyEventDispatcher to the KeyboardFocusManager:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
  .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
      @Override
      public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        // your stuff
        return false;
      }
});
```